# Escape semicolon; MYSQL for Excel

Tags: mysql, excel, escaping

I want to import data from an excel sheet into a MySQL database with the MySQL for Excel plugin. In some cells are texts with semicolons and I already figured out this causes a SQL error. I tried escaping the semicolons with backslash but I still get the error message. How can I escape the semicolon?

Comment: Perhaps you can replace the semicolon with an unused special character (say, ^) in the Excel spreadsheet, import the data into MySQL database, and then replace the ^ character in the database after you have imported.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you converted the cells to a string first using `Cstr(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kai,
this behaviour is purely the fault of MySQL for Excel, and seem to be a bug.

In the meantime, if you are not keen on changing your Excel data as suggested by others there is a workaround:

In your MySQL-for-Excel window click `Options` and then select `Preview SQL statements before they are sent to the server` and `Accept`.

Then proceed as normal with export / append data using the Add-in, but when a `Review SQL script` window appears, copy the contents into a different SQL tool (MySQL workbench, [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/), [SQLWorkbench](http://www.sql-workbench.net/) etc), and run. Then click cancel in the Mysql-for-Excel popups, and refresh the query if necessary.

Also: feel free to report the bug at: http://bugs.mysql.com/

Comment: Had a similar situation with this. Turns out upgrading from version 1.2.0 for mysql for Excell to version 1.2.1 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the semicolon with some unique text e.g. [SEMICOLON].
Next import the data to SQL and run something like

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, '[SEMICOLON]', ';')
WHERE your_field LIKE '%[SEMICOLON]%'
```

Answer (score -1):

I think all you need to do is consider the requirements Excel has when it imports data from CSV files (the parsing rules are probably the same or similar)
In your case, if a field contains any special characters, just quote the values with double quotes before importing the content in Excel.

So:

```
UPDATE table
SET field = '"' || field || '"'
WHERE field like '%,%'
```

The following rules should apply:

- Fields containing a line-break, double-quote, and/or commas should be quoted
- Any field may be quoted (with double quotes)
- A (double) quote character in a field must be represented by two (double) quote characters.

More details: [Wikipedia: Comma-separated values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)